# What do you call a person who dislikes something just because it is trendy?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm trying to describe someone who no longer favor something simply because more people are aware of it/like it now.

Possessive and selfish come pretty close but still not quite what i'm looking for.

Comment: Would a "Hipster" fit this? It's a more modern term, so I'm not too sure of it's use or if it's in dictionaries.

Comment: an anti-cool? - i'm guessing

Comment: We used to call them "punk". :-)

Comment: An elitist snob.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly Contrarian. While it is primarily used in regards to finance/investing, it can be used more generally.
From The Free Dictionary

> [**contrarian**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contrarian)
>
> n.
>   1. a person who takes an opposing view, esp. one who rejects the majority opinion, as in economic matters.

From Urban Dictionary

> **[contrarian](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=contrarian&defid=3905302)** Someone who automatically tends to take the opposite point of view from the person to whom they're speaking, or to
>   disagree with society at large out of a sort of knee-jerk reflex.
>   *Friend: I've got some ice cream, you want vanilla or chocolate? 
>   Contrarian: Um, do you have strawberry? 
>
>   ----  
> Friend: I love indie rock, you heard of these guys?  Contrarian: Yeah, but they're not really that indie, though.*

Comment: Clever answer! A "contrarian snob" would work for me. +1

Comment: Contrarian is perfect! Thank you ~~

Comment: A backwards search for 'contrarian' soon reveals that this is a duplicate.

Comment: I have read the other and wasn't convinced it was exactly a dupe, the motivation for the action seemed different - mistrusting groups rather than misliking popular things. Interestingly on that one, although the OP accepted 'contrarian', they also kind of argued against it in comments...

Comment: Answers were the same, but the questions were different.

Comment: “dislikes something just because it’s trendy” and “opposite of the crowd for just that reason” seem pretty similar to me.  *trendy* = “liked by the crowd”

Comment: The text of the questions are somewhat different, but the questions in the titles are very, very similar. Frankly, I don't think either question's text matches its title or the answer *contrarian*, but *contrarian* matches the question asked in both titles very well.